# org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: error executing work

Tags: java, hibernate, stored-procedures, jdbc, prepared-statement

I am getting the following error when using `session.doWork` here is my code below

```
@Override
    public void linkDeliveryToRack(Session session, final Delivery delivery, final Rack rack) {
        session.doWork(new Work() {

            @Override
            public void execute(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
                PreparedStatement st = connection.prepareStatement("call P_LINK_DELIVERY_TO_RACK (?,?)");
                st.setInt(1, delivery.getIdDelivery());
                st.setInt(2, rack.getIdRack());
                st.execute();
                st.close();
             } 
        });
    }
```

**Error I am getting:**

> WARN - SQL Error: -11, SQLState: 37000 ERROR - Unexpected token:
>   P_LINK_DELIVERY_TO_RACK in statement [call P_LINK_DELIVERY_TO_RACK
>   (?,?)]
>   org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: error executing work     at
>   org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:92)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:52)
>     at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.doWork(SessionImpl.java:2001)     at
>   com.saintgobain.ramses.lib.dao.link.impl.LinkActionProcedureDaoImpl.linkDeliveryToRack(LinkActionProcedureDaoImpl.java:19)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)     at
>   junit.framework.TestCase.runTest(TestCase.java:168)   at
>   junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:134)   at
>   junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:110)     at
>   junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:128)  at
>   junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:113)   at
>   junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:124)   at
>   junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:243)     at
>   junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:238)     at
>   Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Unexpected token:
>   P_LINK_DELIVERY_TO_RACK in statement [call P_LINK_DELIVERY_TO_RACK
>   (?,?)]    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.Util.throwError(Unknown Source)  at
>   org.hsqldb.jdbc.jdbcPreparedStatement.(Unknown Source)  at
>   org.hsqldb.jdbc.jdbcConnection.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)   at
>   com.saintgobain.ramses.lib.dao.link.impl.LinkActionProcedureDaoImpl$1.execute(LinkActionProcedureDaoImpl.java:23)
>     at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.doWork(SessionImpl.java:1997)

**Stored Procedure:** `P_LINK_DELIVERY_TO_RACK`

```
create or replace
PROCEDURE P_LINK_DELIVERY_TO_RACK (p_delivery_id IN NUMBER, p_rack_id IN NUMBER)
IS
   v_count_existing_link   NUMBER;
   v_truck_id              NUMBER;

   CURSOR c_order_items
   IS
      SELECT id_order_item, quantity
        FROM order_item
       WHERE delivery_id = p_delivery_id;
BEGIN
   SELECT TRUCK_ID
     INTO v_truck_id
     FROM rack
    WHERE id_rack = p_rack_id;

   FOR order_item_row IN c_order_items
   LOOP
      SELECT COUNT (0)
        INTO v_count_existing_link
        FROM order_item_link
       WHERE order_item_id = order_item_row.id_order_item
             AND rack_id = p_rack_id;

      IF (v_count_existing_link > 0)
      THEN
         UPDATE order_item_link
            SET truck_id = v_truck_id,
                quantity_rack = order_item_row.quantity,
                date_association = SYSDATE,
                current_flag = 1
          WHERE order_item_id = order_item_row.id_order_item
                AND rack_id = p_rack_id;
      ELSE
         INSERT INTO order_item_link
              VALUES (order_item_link_seq.NEXTVAL,
                      order_item_row.id_order_item,
                      p_rack_id,
                      v_truck_id,
                      order_item_row.quantity,
                      SYSDATE,
                      1);
      END IF;
   END LOOP;
EXCEPTION
   WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND
   THEN
      NULL;
   WHEN OTHERS
   THEN
      -- Consider logging the error and then re-raise
      RAISE;
END P_LINK_DELIVERY_TO_RACK;
```

The stored procedure i executed in **sqldeveloper** and it worked using dummy data :

```
execute P_LINK_DELIVERY_TO_RACK(2,1);
```

But don't know why I'm getting error `Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Unexpected token: P_LINK_DELIVERY_TO_RACK in statement [call P_LINK_DELIVERY_TO_RACK (?,?)]`

Please help me out.

Comment: try this 
`PreparedStatement st = connection.prepareStatement("{ call P_LINK_DELIVERY_TO_RACK (?,?) }");`

Comment: Hi @tbsalling : i'm using Oracle SQL DEVELOPER (Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.1.0)

Comment: Hi @L.Young : i tried that too but not working :(

Comment: @techGaurdian I'm comparing your code to mine and I think the problem is that you are using a `PreparedStatement` but you need to use a `CallableStatement` like this `CallableStatement statement = connection.prepareCall(sql);`

Comment: @L.Young : i tried using CallableStatement. but getting error 'Unexpected token: P_LINK_DELIVERY_TO_RACK in statement [  call P_LINK_DELIVERY_TO_RACK (?,?)  ]
 at org.hsqldb.jdbc.Util.throwError(Unknown Source)
 at org.hsqldb.jdbc.jdbcCallableStatement.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at org.hsqldb.jdbc.jdbcConnection.prepareCall(Unknown Source) ' 
Which jar (version) you used may i know ?

Comment: I am using oracle-ojdbc6-11.2.0.3.0.jar

Did you try the `CallableStatement` with the `{ call P_LINK_DELIVERY_TO_RACK (?,?) }` ?

Comment: yes i tried with CallableStatement with the { call P_LINK_DELIVERY_TO_RACK (?,?) }